# Is there a way to get dot product of two huge matrix using pandas or pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I'm doing collaborative filtering and in predict phase I need to get matrix multiplication of two big matrices(4mln x 7 and 25k x 7) for SVD predictions. Is there an efficient and fast way to so, maybe using pandas or pyspark

Right now I came up with solution to get dot product row by row but that is time consuming:

```
for i in range(products):
    user_ratings = np.dot(X_products[i], X_user)
    m = np.min(user_ratings)
    items[:,-1] = j
    ratings[:,-1] = user_ratings
    reorder_cols = np.fliplr(np.argsort(ratings, axis = 1))

    rows = np.arange(num_users)[:,np.newaxis]
    # reorder
    ratings = ratings[rows, reorder_cols]
    items = items[rows, reorder_cols]
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: What is the "dot product of matrices"? The dot product is usually defined on vectors ("1D matrices") only, and then only if they are the same dimension. (Or do you mean this [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Dyadics_and_matrices) that I'd never heard of, but is only defined on matrices of the same size?)

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, you are right. I mean matrix multiplication

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using pyspark's [`mllib.linalg.distributed`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#module-pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed) module. suppose your big matrices are `M1` & `M2` and you have converted them into RDDs.
1. convert them into BlockMatrices.

```
bm_M1 = IndexedRowMatrix(M1.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x:
                     (x[1],Vectors.dense(x[0])))).toBlockMatrix(10,10)
bm_M2 = IndexedRowMatrix(M2.ZipWithIndex().map(lambda x:
                     (x[1],Vectors.dense(x[0])))).toBlockMatrix(10,10)
```

2.  transpose bm_M2 and multiply

```
bm_M1.multiply(bm_M2.transpose())
```

An example

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import *

mat = sc.parallelize(np.random.rand(4,4))


bm_M1 = IndexedRowMatrix(mat.zipWithIndex().map(lambda x:
                     (x[1],Vectors.dense(x[0])))).toBlockMatrix(1,1)
```

Comment: I create BlockMatrixs:`M1 = BlockMatrix(sc.parallelize(X_user), 3, 2) M2 = BlockMatrix(sc.parallelize(X_products), 3, 2)` and got `TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'numpy.ndarray'> into a sub-matrix block tuple`

Comment: You have to supply a tuple of sub-blocks for creating the block matrix directly. It would be better if you create an IndexedRowMatix and convert it  to BlockMatrix. I have added an example to make it clear to you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it seems that my code is more efficient than yours on my environment